# Unable to Dual boot Laptop with ubuntu 17.04

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 17.04 but when I make partition and click on Install it shows this error:

```
the attempt to mount a filesystem with type vfat failed /boot/efi
```

and after that installation process didn't complete.

What should I do? I always get this error whenever I try to install any Linux.

Comment: You may simply need to disable [Fast Startup](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-10-a.html) and [Hibernate](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2859-hibernate-enable-disable-windows-10-a.html) in *Windows.* (Note that the firmware "fast start" feature is completely unrelated and would not cause this problem.)

Comment: If you create a partition for Linux / (root) then it must be a Linux formatted partition not a Windows formatted partition like NTFS or FAT32. Ubuntu installs default to ext4, so that is normal suggestion. See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu